# how can i remove one of multiple ubuntu partitions on a windows 10 dual boot UEFI laptop

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I can find plenty of info on totally removing Ubuntu from dual boot, but I just want to remove one of three.  I can select Windows or one of the other two and they boot up just fine.  I would like to remove the (partition deleted) one from the menu.  Thank You in advance.

Comment: You have to know which install is grub using to boot from. Typically last install or last version with major update to grub. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I am talking with a second computer.  No paste possible but I just downloaded the Ubuntu Dist within the last two weeks.

Comment: Do I understand well : you have at boot time a menu where you can choose to boot up with two times ubuntu and one windows?  Have you installed ubuntu twice?

Comment: Yes, I have three versions of Ubuntu and I deleted the partition of one of them.  It  still shows up on the boot menu.

Comment: I'm assuming that I need to fix Grub then tell windows what I did. (oversimplification).

Comment: Did you run sudo update-grub on the Ubuntu which controls the grub boot? That should just rewrite the grub.cfg file and get rid of the old boot menu item.

Comment: I have tried that.  update-grub does not fix.  Guess I'll just play with this some more.  Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Install in Ubuntu "Grub-customizer".You find here how to do this. https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
The method is the same for Ubuntu 20.04 etc.
With this application you can remove the unwanted "ubuntu" from the boot menu.